# How to call an http endpoint using the `https.get(...)` method in the Node.js https library

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to call a basic endpoint to parse the json data it exposes. The data is served up using a REST endpoint I run locally on my machine. The URL is simple and open on port 80 only (no SSL or TLS on port 443).

When I call the endpoint using the following code I get this error:

`ncaught NodeError: Protocol "http:" not supported. Expected "https:"`

Here is my typescript code:

```
var req = https.get(`http://localhost/events/recent`, (response) => {
    var responseCode;
    var responseBody = [];
    response.on("data", (data) => {
        responseBody.push(data);
    });
    response.on("end", (data) => {
        var result = Buffer.concat(responseBody);
        responseCode = response.statusCode;
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            processResult(result);
        }
        else {
            console.log(`The Response failed with status code: ${responseCode}`);
        }
    });
});
req.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are using the `https` library. To use the `http` library, change the first line of your code to the following:

```
var req = http.get(`http://localhost/events/recent`, (response) => {
```

See how you originally had `https`, meaning that the function expected an `https` beginning address.

Comment: I did have to update my imports to include the http library you suggested. But that worked after the import statement was added too: `import http = require("http")`